# Generic parameter is lost in `Supplier` lambda but not in `Callable`

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Can anybody explain why generic parameter is lost in `Supplier` lambda but not in `Callable`?

I created interface that captures generic type and helper function that instantiates it

```
abstract class TypeRef<T> protected constructor() {
    val type: Type = (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]

    override fun toString(): String {
        return type.toString()
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> getTypeRef(): TypeRef<T> {
    return object: TypeRef<T>() {};
}
```

But testing it leads to different results depending on where it's called

```
inline fun <reified T> testTypeRef(): TypeRef<T> {
    val ref0 = getTypeRef<T>()
    println("In root $ref0")

    Callable {
        val ref1 = getTypeRef<T>()
        println("In callable $ref1")
    }.call()

    Supplier {
        val ref2 = getTypeRef<T>()
        println("In supplier $ref2")
        ""
    }.get()

    return ref0
}
```

produces

```
In root java.util.List<? extends java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference<java.lang.String>>
In callable java.util.List<? extends java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference<java.lang.String>>
In supplier T
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Looks like it's Kotlin bug. One user created issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34856